# Batch command for "list-contains" operation

Tags: list, command-line, batch-file, logical-operators

I have this command that goes through all folders in a directory and deletes all of them except one:

```
FOR /D %i IN ("Directory\*") DO IF /I NOT "%i" == "FolderToKeep" RD /S/Q "%i"
```

Now I need it to keep two specific folders instead of just one. At first I thought it was just about adding some simple OR logic to the comparison, but it seems that batch does not support logical operators like OR and AND. So what is the best way of achieving this? If the OR command does not exist, maybe there is functionality that lets you test if the variable is contained in a list? Something like this maybe?

```
FOR /D %i IN ("Directory\*") DO IF /I NOT "%i" IN "FolderToKeep","FolderToKeep2" RD /S/Q "%i"
```

I am not familiar with batch coding, so excuse me if this seems trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "exclusion=\FolderToKeep\FolderToKeep2\"
FOR /d %%i IN (directory\*) DO (
    IF /i "!exclusion:\%%~nxi\=!" equ "%exclusion%" RD /S/Q "%%~i"
)
```

Comment: @Endoro: You beat me for a couple minutes! :-)

Comment: +1, but you should use `%~NXi` since a folder name may include an extension. Also, the technique fails if a folder name contains `=`.

Answer (score 5):

Try it with nested `IF`s

```
FOR /D %i IN ("Directory\*") DO (
   IF /I NOT "%i" == "FolderToKeep" (
      IF /I NOT "%i" == "FolderToKeep2" RD /S/Q "%i"
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked like a charm. And I hate batch :)

Comment: @KnutMarius - You should brush up on your boolean logic rules, it will help with any programming, not just batch. Your original problem of `if not (a or b)` is equivalent to `if not a and not b`, and jeb's answer is basically the latter.

Comment: I know enough about logic rules to fully understand this, but I am more or less blank on batch, so it was more about the syntax than anything else.. The reason why I marked this as an answer is because it solved my problem, and it was the only answer when I marked it

Answer (score 5):

The "test if the variable is contained in a list" can be easily achieved by defining a variable with the list of desired values and then trying to delete a specific value from the list: if the list changes, then the value was in the list. The only detail with this method is to separate the values in the list with a delimiter character that can not appear in the values, and include the same delimiter when the specific value is deleted.

Also, because this method requires Delayed Expansion, it can not be used in the command-line (unless you previously enable it).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set foldersToKeep=/FolderToKeep/FolderToKeep2/
FOR /D %%i IN ("Directory\*") DO (
   IF "!foldersToKeep:/%%~Ni/=!" equ "%foldersToKeep%" RD /S/Q "%%i"
)
```

By the while, in your method you should use `"%~Ni"` to get just the folder name because the list of names returned by the FOR include the `Directory\...` part, that is, there is no way that `"Directory\FolderToKeep"` be equal to `"FolderToKeep"`.

Comment: +1, but you should use `%~NXi` since a folder name may include an extension. Also, the technique fails if a folder name contains `=`.